# Dynamically access class and its property in C#

Tags: c#

I need to access something like `strClassname.strPropertyName` I will have different values for `strClassname` and `strProperty` name in program execution.

Please direct me in right way.

Comment: Can you explain further? How do the names vary? How do you know which classname and which property to find? Are they parameters?

Comment: You need to google for "reflection c#" - see if you can figure it out, or ask again with a more specific question.

Comment: You may be making your program more complicated, because usually there will be some simpler alternative ways without needing to "dynamically accessing class fields".

Comment: i tried with reflection but i need some thing like i have 1000 class in  project i need to access only few hundred of them and for which i have to collect value of its name property

Comment: @RahulVasantraoKamble did you know that you can write Linq queries against `Assembly.GetTypes` or `Type.GetProperties`. [See this for an example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3016555/119477)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use reflection:

To get names of properties for a specific type use method Type.GetProper­ties. Method returns array of PropertyInfo objects and the property names are available through PropertyInfo.Name property. If you want to get only subset of all properties (e.g. only public static ones) use BindingFlags when calling GetProperties method. You have to specify at least two flags, one from Public/NonPublic and one of Instance/Static flags. If you use GetProperties without a BindingFlags parameter, default flags are Public + NonPublic + Instance.

Following example shows how to get public static properties.

```
using System.Reflection;  // reflection namespace

// get all public static properties of MyClass type
PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos;
propertyInfos = typeof(MyClass).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public |
                                              BindingFlags.Static);
// sort properties by name
Array.Sort(propertyInfos,
        delegate(PropertyInfo propertyInfo1, PropertyInfo propertyInfo2)
        { return propertyInfo1.Name.CompareTo(propertyInfo2.Name); });

// write property names
foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in propertyInfos)
{
  Console.WriteLine(propertyInfo.Name);
}
```

[[Source](http://www.csharp-examples.net/reflection-property-names/)]

Answer (score 18):

Sounds to me like you are trying to get (or set) the value of a property on an object at runtime. So here's the most basic way to do this:

```
public static object GetPropertyValue(object instance, string strPropertyName)
{
    Type type = instance.GetType();
    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo propertyInfo = type.GetProperty(strPropertyName);
    return propertyInfo.GetValue(instance, null);
}
```

... and to set a value:

```
public static void SetPropertyValue(object instance, string strPropertyName, object newValue)
{
    Type type = instance.GetType();
    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo propertyInfo = type.GetProperty(strPropertyName);
    propertyInfo.SetValue(instance, newValue, null);
}
```

If you're attempting to get the names of properties of a class, here's a function for that:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetPropertyNames(string className)
{
    Type type = Type.GetType(className);
    return type.GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name);
}
```

Say that you have 100 objects, and you want to get the value of the Name property on each of them, here's a function that will do that:

```
public static IEnumerable<String> GetNames(IEnumerable<Object> objects, string nameProperty = "Name")
{
    foreach (var instance in objects)
    {
        var type = instance.GetType();
        var property = type.GetProperty(nameProperty);
        yield return property.GetValue(instance, null) as string;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if there's a hundred or so classes and you know you want to access a specific property on each and you know every class will be instantiated, you should *definitely* consider creating an interface holding the property you wish to access ex.

```
public interface INamed
{
    Name { get; }
}
```

Example usage:

```
var namedInstances = listOfClasses.Of<INamed>().Cast<INamed>();

foreach(var instance in namedInstances)
{
    var name = instance.Name;
}
```

On the other hand, if you're not planning to instantiate these classes, you could try the following approach instead if the 'Name' property is static or const:

```
public interface INamed { } //Marker interface

public static class GetNamedHelper
{
    private static IEnumerable<Type> GetAssemblyTypes(IEnumerable<Assembly> assemblies)
    {
        if (assemblies == null) yield break;

        foreach (var assembly in assemblies.Where(assembly => assembly != null))
        {
            IEnumerable<Type> types;
            try
            {
                types = assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t != null);
            }
            catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException rtle)
            {
                types = rtle.Types.Where(t => t != null);
            }
            foreach (var type in types)
                yield return type;
        }
    }

    private static readonly Type namedMarkerInterface = typeof (INamed);

    public static IEnumerable<string> GetNames(params Assembly[] assemblies)
    {
        var types = GetAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
            .Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Any(intf => intf == namedMarkerInterface));

        foreach (var type in types)
        {
            //ex. public static string Name
            var prop = type.GetProperty("Name", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
            if (prop == null || !prop.CanRead) continue;
            yield return prop.GetValue(null, null) as string;

            //ex. public const string Name
            var field = type.GetField("Name", BindingFlags.Public);
            if (field == null || !field.IsStatic) continue;
            yield return field.GetValue(null) as string;
        }
    }
}
```

Eitherway, you need to know which classes to check and for what.